# Generating the Word Document with SharePoint list data without using Open XML

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow, word, word-automation

I would like to have Word document which would be automatically filled with data stored in the SharePoint List. When data in The List would be added, changed or deleted corresponding data in Word document should also be added, changed or deleted. Do you know the simplest method to create such automation: Word document generating process filled with all data came from concrete columns (e.g 2 out of 10 columns) from the SharePoint list.

I have known that Open XML SDK 2.0 allows such thing, but currently i am not able to use this application. I am wondering whether SharePoint workflows and SharePoint Designer could create such process.

Is anybody who has the knowledge of it and advise how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SharePoint workflow functionality from SharePoint designer to do this:

1. Create a custom list that stores you info
2. Create a document library, set its default document to the word template you want to use
3. Edit the word template form the document library (Remeber that you need the same columns as in your custom list, I suggest using the same content type)
4. In MS Word, go to the insert section on the ribbon, choose Quick Parts, you can now select columns from the list to insert here
5. Create a Workflow that runs on the custom list, all this workflow needs to do is run CreateListItem to you document library. SharePoint will do the rest for you

NOTE: Running workflows as the admin account wont do anything, it will not start automatically.

Comment: Thank you Robert for your answer, buti don't havedata in the Listso this Word document should be autoamtically updated. when an item is created in the List, new Word document in the Library appears (but only with this data from one List item). So many documents are created, no only one with merged data. Maybe is it a possibility to create scond workflow which will merge all data from this Word documents? Anther issue is i need also: when an item in the List is updated- data in Word document are also automatically updated; when an item in List is deleted- related Word document is also deleted.